# How could Datatime form send epoch format instead of formated date?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, epoch

I would like to send epoch format value of user datetime selection when the form is been submitted

Would you please tell me how i do that ?
http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/datetimeform/gpio/test5.htm

I expect to send epoch data with GET method like this : /test5.htm?datetime=1494335700

at the moment it sends outstanding format what would not be usuable in backend :

/test5.htm?datetime=29+December+2016+-+10%3A50&submit=

--

By the way, for some unknown reasons 'Delete' and 'Calendar' graphicon icons won't be displayed in the datetimeform even css file is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the '[DateTimePicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)' library you're using doesn't seem to have any support for this, you'll have to patch it yourself.

Firstly give the existing `#dtp_input1` element a `name` so that it will be sent as a parameter:

```html
<input id="dtp_input1" name="dtp_input1" type="hidden"/>
```

Next we need to hook the picker's `setValue()` method in order to put the field's value into the format we want:

```js
/* get the datetimepicker controller */
let picker = $(`.form_datetime`).data(`datetimepicker`);

/* override its setValue() method */
let f = picker.setValue;
picker.setValue = function(...xs) {
    /* call the original method first */
    f.call(this, ...xs);
    /* now set the linked field to epoch format */
    $(`#${this.linkField}`)
        .val(`${(this.getDate() || new Date(0)).getTime()}`);
};
```

Now when you submit the form it should yield a query something like this:

`?datetime=20+January+2017+-+03%3A15&dtp_input1=1484842500000`

where `dtp_input1` is the epoch value and `datetime` is the human-readable string from the text box.

Comment: Many thanks, it is exactly what i was looking for.  However i tried to apply the code you provided but epoch time is not returned.  Did i miss something ?  Is "moment.js" library needed for time conversion to epoch form ? (i added it)   http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/datetimeform/gpio/test7.htm

Comment: You changed the field ID to "epoch" but set the "data-link-field" attribute to "dtp", that's probably why it's not working.

Comment: You are right, that was the issue, many many thanks.  Could it be possible to hide / not send the datetime formated selection into the GET form and keep only epoch parameter ?  Anyway your first answer helped me a lot.

Comment: yes I think you can just remove the `name="datetime"` attribute from the `<input>` text box.

Comment: I'm now trying to send epoch time with EOSNASDAN datetime picker library, but for some reasons i can't apply the way you suggested on it. Could you please tell me what i did wrong ?  http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/datetimeform/gpio/test-eonasdan-dtp-form.htm

Comment: well if you're now using a completely different library then none of my earlier suggestions will apply to it, i was relying on the internal details of the original library. i'll take a look at your new thing later if i have time — until then, scour the documentation of the new library for any features that might be related to epoch/raw time formats.

Comment: EONASDAN library handles epoch time format, but i don't know how i could link to my existing datetime form another hidden field that would content epoch time, that one would be send with GET method when submit button is clicked.

Comment: okay it looks like for the EONASDAN library you don't need any of that `data-link-field=…` stuff. instead  just listen for the change event like this: https://gist.github.com/Cauterite/6f449058ab9f585b27906df0ce7c303a

Comment: I would like to round the returned epoch timestamp to the next minute (no seconds anymore) , so far submitted timestamp includes seconds. I tried the following but it does not work, can you tell me what is wrong ?[See CODE](https://image.ibb.co/gd5JZv/Screen_Hunter_01_Aug_08_22_41.png)

Comment: sorry @LaurentCoulon i forgot to respond to your messages, since i have been very busy with work lately. you can try something like this: `rounded = date; rounded.setMilliseconds(0); rounded.setSeconds(0); if (date.getSeconds() || date.getMilliseconds()) {rounded.setTime(rounded.getTime() + (60 * 1000));};`